# How to connect to server running on the system with password protection in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I am new to this site. I am facing a problem with socket programming in Java. I have written a server, which processes the clients. Everything is fine and working ordinarily.

What should I do if the network on which I want to run the server is password protected? That means we have to provide the username and the password of the system on which we want to login?

If I am running the server on this kind of protected network and trying to connect via client, the client socket is not getting created, because the server is refusing the connection.

Comment: Are you using ssh/telnet to connect? IF yes, how about using http://commons.apache.org/net/ Telnet apis to connect?

Comment: what kind of authentication system provides your network?

Comment: The authentication system is like when i am trying to login to any other system on the network by giving its ip address in the run it asks for the username and the password of the system to which i want to connect to..what to do in this case??

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood something.  If you wrote a socket server, then it is your code which must do authentication.  Logging in to a user session, whether it be Windows RDP or ssh, has nothing to do with your socket server's connection.  Please try to explain your question more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I am running the server on this kind of protected network and
>   trying to connect via client, the client socket is not getting
>   created, because the server is refusing the connection.

There are many reasons why a server could be refusing the connection.  If you can connect when the client and server are running on the same machine, but not when the client is on a different machine, the problem likely is that the server is running a firewall and not allowing connections from "outside".

If the client is on a completely different network segment, i.e. the client is somewhere on the Internet "far" away, then there could be multiple firewalls between the two systems, any of which could be rejecting the connection.

Another possibility is that when the server opens its `ServerSocket`, you bound it to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`.  In this case, the server could accept connections only from `localhost`, i.e. originating on the same machine.  It would be completely unaware of connection originating anywhere else.

Without a much better explanation of how the client and server are situated, it is not possible to give a better answer.  One thing is certain however: the fact that you require authentication to "login" to a system has nothing to do with your situation.

Comment: Hi Jim,
Yes you are right,i unserstood the problem wrong...
thanks a lot for the right direction...